# Couchbase server Restore

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-sync-gateway

I am trying to restore a couchbase base from the backup file. I used the following command:

```
./cbrestore 
/backup/2019-02-06T121650Z-full 
http://127.0.0.1:8091 
-u Administrator -p password 
–bucket-source=my_bucket 
–bucket-destination=my_bucket
```

When I run the command I get the following error:

```
s0 error: async operation: error: conn.send() exception: 
[Errno 32] Broken pipe on sink: http://10.128.0.2:8091(my_bucket@10.128.0.2:8091) 
error: conn.send() exception: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

I used:

```
couchbase-server5.1.1 community edition
```

My backup has the sync_gateways sync data also:

```
couchbase-sync-gateway 1.5.1 version
```

Comment: Can you get me a version number for the cbrestore that you are using?